# (PHP) The include function only includes some parts of the file

Tags: php, file, web, include

I have a problem including a php file. I have searched on the web, and troubleshooted in different ways for three hours, But I can't figure it out on my own.

I have a file called "side9test.php" with this code:

```
<?php

include "styret/fil-liste.php"; 

?>
```

The file "fil-liste.php" contains:

```
<?php
echo "</br>";
echo file_get_contents("filsystem_navn/m_0.txt");

?>
```

The file "m_0.txt" contains this:

```
forste mappa
```

The problem though, When I run "side9test.php", all it gives me is:

```
</br>
```

I appreciate all feedback!

Comment: `file_get_contents` returns `false` on failure. Have you checked for that? Could be a problem with the (relative...) path.

Comment: `var_dump(file_exists("filsystem_navn/m_0.txt"));`

Comment: @jeroen Hmmm, haven't checked if it returns false, but I have checked that the folder and file names are correct.

Comment: @MarkBaker I added "var_dump(file_exists("filsystem_navn/m_0.txt"));" to the file "side9test.php" and the file returned "</br>bool(false)"

Comment: Then the file isn't being included at all, and file_get_contents() is returning a false. Make sure the relative path is correct to your current working directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your file path is correct, Just change your code to
          `echo file_get_contents("filsystem_navn/m_0.txt",true);`

setting to `true` or `1` will search for include path :)